# Expo Development Certificate Fetching Error on MacBook: Fallback to Cached Certificate

Tags: expo

I'm encountering an issue while developing an app with Expo on my MacBook. Every time I run my project using Expo CLI, I encounter the following error message:

> There was an error fetching the Expo development certificate, falling back to cached certificate

This error seems to be related to the Expo development certificate, but I'm unsure about how to resolve it. I've searched through the Expo documentation and online forums, but haven't found a clear solution.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Operating System: macOS (**macOS Sonoma**)
- Expo SDK version: (**49 SDK**)
- Node.js version: (**v19.7.0**)

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Checked my internet connection to ensure it's stable.
2. Made sure my macOS firewall isn't blocking Expo's network requests.
3. Updated my Expo CLI to the latest version.
4. Cleared Expo's cache using `expo -c` and restarted the project.
5. Verified that my system's date and time settings are accurate.
6. Despite trying these steps, I still encounter the same error. The project does continue to work using the cached certificate, but I'm concerned that this might lead to issues in the future.

Has anyone else experienced this error while developing with Expo on a MacBook? Are there any additional troubleshooting steps I could try? I'd appreciate any insights or solutions to resolve this issue and ensure a smooth development experience.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is still having this issue with development sertificate.

Expo uses a development certificate to secure your app during development. Make sure your Expo development certificate is not expired or corrupted. I managed to solve mine in this way, and you can try to reset it using the following command:

```
npx expo build:ios --clear-credentials
```

After running the command, follow the prompts to create a new development certificate.

Comment: That command is no longer supported. `$ expo build:ios is not supported in the local CLI, please use eas build -p ios instead`. I have other issues, so I can't test that alternative command.